# First preference to routing then to static file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my `RouteConfig.cs`

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {     
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("dark")]
public class DarkController : Controller
{
    public DarkController()
    {
        this.ViewBag.LayoutName = "_DarkLayout.cshtml";
    }

    [Route("index.html")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here if I visit `/Dark/index.html` it loads the physical `index.html` file present in `Dark` folder but if I remove the index.html file from my dark folder my route seems to work fine.

I just want to give 1st preference to my route and if that is not found then it should go to physical file. Here it seems the opposite is happening and first preference is given to physical file and if that is not found then my routes are hit.

I have this in my web.config as well:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
    <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
</modules>
```

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `HttpHandler` for `*.html` files, and route inside handler.

For example:

```
public class HtmlFileHandler: IHttpHandler
{        
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var htmlFileRequested = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments.Contains(".html");
        if (htmlFileRequested)
        {
          // return file by context.Response.WriteFile("");
          // don't forget: context.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
        else
        {
          //redirect to controller factory
        }
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        // To enable pooling, return true here.
        // This keeps the handler in memory.
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.html" 
         type="HtmlFileHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

---

[More information about custom HttpHandlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)